# Wiring dependencies in a Spring unit test without using @RunWith

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, integration-testing

I am using spring 3 mvc/security frameworks.

I have created a Controller class that has a reference to a repository to load data from. The class is annotated with `@Controller`, the repository class is annotated with `@Repository`, and the instance of the respository is `@Autowired`.

However when I try to unit test, the autowired instance throws a null pointer exception.

Now, I understand that because it is autowired, it needs to be within the spring context to be picked up. But I feel that if I use `@RunsWith()` then it becomes an integration test. I would really like to separate the integration tests (using `@RunsWith`) and the unit test for this method. Any ideas on how I can get around this null pointer exception? Would just creating getter/setter methods on my controller class be okay?:

Repository class:

```
@Repository
public class Repository{
 ....
}
```

Controller class:

```
@Controller
public class Controller{
@Autowired
private Repository repo;
....
public String showView(){
    repo.doSomething();
}
```

Test class:

```
public ControllerTest {
@Test
public shouldDoTestOfShowView(){
}
}
```

Comment: so would creating the getter/setters in the controller be best practice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally tend to use [@Simon's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9213414/21234), rather than exposing setters, although either approach is fine. Adding setters just for the sake of tests is a bit annoying, though.

An alternative is to use [Spring's `ReflectionTestUtils` class](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/util/ReflectionTestUtils.html) to directly poke dependencies into the field using reflection, removing the need for special constructors and setters, e.g.

```
public ControllerTest {
   @Test
   public shouldDoTestOfShowView() {
      Controller controller = new Controller();
      Repository repository = new Repository();

      ReflectionTestUtils.setField(controller, "repo", repository); 
   }
}
```

Whether or not that still constitutes an "integration test" is your call (I don't).

Comment: I think the reflectionTestUtils may be my best bet. But in my case, my repo has an autowired entityManager, so I will have to figure out how to do nested reflections.

Answer (score 2):

I always write 2 constructors. One without arguments for Spring and a protected one with all the dependencies for unit testing.

```
@Controller
public class Controller{
@Autowired
private Repository repo;

public Controller() {
    super();
}

protected Controller(Repositoy repo) {
    this();
    this.repo = repo;
}
```

Comment: Why not just have a single constructor which is @Autowired? Instead of using field level Autowiring?

Comment: If you use XML configurations, you can use only 1 constructor with @Autowired on it. If you use Java based configurations, you have to instantiate the class in Java and having an empty constructor is handy.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, I would provide setters just for testing purposes, but if you are concerned about consumers of your code using them improperly, perhaps you want to use an approach that utilizes reflection.

I have written a utility in the past which takes in two arguments, a target object and an object you are setting on your target.

```
public static void set(Object target, Object setMeOnTarget) {
    //
}
```

What you can do from here is introspect on the fields of `target`, looking for Spring's supported autowiring annotations (`@Autowired`, `@Resource`, `@Inject`, maybe even `@Value`) and see if `setMeOnTarget` can be assigned to that field (I used `Class.isAssignableFrom(Class)`).

It may be a bit frail (Spring suddenly stops supporting these annotations...not likely...), but it has worked great for me.